# If i want to store data from an input with multiple lines am i best using an Arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Im trying to craete a program in order for a player to submit their name, what teams they have played for, what numbers they were, and the average amount of time they spent on the field playig the game for each team. So, saying their was up to 50 lines of inputs.

if the input was something like this:

```
<nameOfplayer>
<teamName1> : <No.team1> : <gametime1>
<teamName2> : <No.team2> : <gametime2>
```

so on so forth.....

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend a HashMap, ArrayList, String[] mixture.

Basically here, a String[] would have the team name, number, and game time.

You can easily fetch all of a players team history by using players.get(player);

I wrote this small piece of code up.

```
HashMap < String, ArrayList < String[] > players = new HashMap < String, ArrayList < String[] > ();

public void addPlayersTeam(String player, String teamName, String teamNumber, String gameTime) {
    if (players.containsKey(player)) {
        ArrayList < String[] > teamHistory = players.get(player);
        String[] new history = {
            teamName, teamNumber, gameTime
        };
        teamHistory.add(history);
    } else {
        ArrayList < String[] > teamHistory = new ArrayList < String[] > ();
        String[] new history = {
            teamName, teamNumber, gameTime
        };
        teamHistory.add(history);
    }
}
```